# LOAD DATA INFILE syntax error in LOAD... SQL & Java

Tags: java, sql, bulkinsert, sql-insert, load-data-infile

I am trying to run insert statements using load data infile (also tried load data local infile) in my Java Program and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Either it's the SQL statement or the filename/path... 
I feel my filename/path is wrong. In Eclipse, I added a .txt file in the project folder.

I tried to get the path of the file by using getAbsolutePath but I still the error saying there's a syntax error in load.

Here's where I am trying to write the insert statement: 
I've also changed the " to ' in my statement because i've seen so many versions of how to write this. I changed the file.getabsolutepath in the part of the insert statement to just filename.

```
    String filename = "studentData.txt";
    String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File file = new File(workingDirectory, filename);

    System.out.println("Final filepath : " + file.getAbsolutePath());

    sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE \"" + file.getAbsolutePath()
            + "\" INTO TABLE STUDENT FIELDS "
            + "TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' "
            + "(STUDENT_ID, NAME, MAJOR, GRADE);";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

Here is what my error is saying:

Final filepath : /Users/amnakhan/Documents/workspace/DatabaseExample/studentData.txt

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: near "LOAD": syntax error
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:397)
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeUpdate(JDBC3Statement.java:116)
at DatabaseAccessHelper.createTables(DatabaseAccessHelper.java:72)
at DatabaseAccessHelper.main(DatabaseAccessHelper.java:296)
```

My program was working fine.. if I hard code in the insert statements, the program works fine. So I know everything else is okay. I am trying to just load a text file and run the insert statements.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try single quotes around the path like `sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "' INTO`? Did you check `sql` on `System.out` as you do with the path?

Comment: I did try with single quote... it didn't work. I still get an error. And I did, but nothing yet. I am not sure why it's not working. And what it means the error is near "load"

Comment: I get this when I print: LOAD DATA INFILE 'studentData.txt' INTO TABLE STUDENT FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (STUDENT_ID, NAME, MAJOR, GRADE);

Comment: I changed it to filename instead of absolutepath...

Comment: You checked studentData.txt to work from inside the database, didn't you? Actually, why is it `stmt.executeUpdate`, not `stmt.execute`?

Comment: I changed that also to only execute. It still gives me an error. And it runs perfectly when I run it in sql from the terminal.